# Delete data out of histogram in excel

Tags: excel, histogram, excel-2010, excel-charts

I've got a histogram in excel

data :
[image]

I've added a histogram with a bin width of 4.
I've added an overflow of 10
and an underflow bin of 10:
[image]

I'd like to remove anything with a bin width less than 10, can anyone help me please?

T.I.A

Comment: Could you explain a bit more plz? According to your description, the only bins left if you removed anything with a bin width less than 10 would be the underflow and overflow bins and I don't think that's what you mean?

Comment: Hi, that is what I mean. Maybe a bad example as there's not much data there. I'm just trying to work out how I would remove that if I needed to? Thanks!